# ¿Porqué no se está aplicando los estilos CSS?

Tags: php, html, css

Estoy haciendo una página html, css y php pero no se por qué no se aplica el estilo css. El archivo css está funcionando en otras páginas. Este es el código:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>INICIO - ISFT194</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div  class="container">
        <?php
            session_start();
            $email =  $_SESSION["email"];
            include("conexion.php");
            include_once "conexion.php";
            $consulta = "SELECT nombre, apellido, email, dni FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$_SESSION[email]'";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $consulta);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                echo "<table class='container'>";
                echo "<tr class='table'>";
                echo "<td>NOMBRE: </td>";
                echo "<td>".$row["nombre"]."</td>";
                echo "</tr>"; 
                echo "<td>APELLIDO: </td>";
                echo "<td>".$row["apellido"]."</td>"; 
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>EMAIL: </td>";
                echo "<td>".$row["email"]."</td>";
                echo "</tr>"; 
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>DNI: </td>";
                echo "<td>".$row["dni"]."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";    
            }
            echo "<table>";

        ?>
        <select class="login-text" method="POST" name="carrera">
        <?php 
            //cargar la lista de carreras
            $csql = "SELECT carreras.nombre FROM carreras INNER JOIN usuariocarrera ON carreras.id = usuariocarrera.idcarrera INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuariocarrera.idusuario = (SELECT usuarios.id WHERE usuarios.email = '$email')";
            $sql = mysqli_query($link, $csql);
            while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<option value=". $row['nombre'] .">" . $row['nombre'] . "</option>";
            }
        ?>
        </select><br><br>
        <?php
            echo "<a href='inscripcion.php' >Inscribirse a una carrera </a>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<a href='delogueo.php' >Cerrar sesion </a>";
        ?>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Y donde les estas diciendo que use ese archivo css?

Comment: Falta la etiqueta `link` del **`CSS`**

Comment: Hola :) Creo que no estas indicando donde está el archivo css con la etiqueta Link :)

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo, no tienes vinculado tu Código html con tu CSS, para hacerlo, tienes que poner dentro de head, una etiqueta así `<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos/estilos.css">` Donde href es la dirección a la que se buscarán los estilos. Espero que te sirva.

En caso de que el css esté en una carpeta más arriba que el HTML con el que estás trabajando, tendrías que poner en el href dos puntos y una barra, lo que hará que se busque en las carpetas de más arriba.  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../estilos/estilos.css">`

Saludos!